# Mocking inherited methods

Tags: python, unit-testing, lambda

Please forgive my noob status, but I have come across a construct I don't really understand and hope someone can explain it for me.

```
class Base(object):
    def mogrify(self, column):
        return self.mogrifiers.get(column.lower().strip()) or (lambda x: x)
```

...

```
class MyClass(some.package.Base):
    def mogrifiers(self):
        return {
            'column1': (lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x)))
        }
```

...

```
class MyOtherClass(object):
    def convert_columns:
        ...
        new_row[colkey] = self.myclass.mogrify(colkey)(value)
```

This all works, but I'm trying to write a unit test and mock out `MyClass`.

As far as I can tell, mogrifiers returns a dictionary of all the columns and any transformations that are required.

The code I am testing calls **mogrify** (inherited from the Base class) with a specific column name in a string.

This tries to extract the column from the dictionary and returns the lambda function ? or if it doesn't exist in the dictionary, it returns a lambda that just gives the string back ?

So that just leaves me with the **(value)** bit in the code I'm trying to test. It's no clear what it does.

If I don't want to test the underlying conversion/transformation my mock could just return the simple lambda.

So I've done that, but it throws an exception on the call to mogrify saying:

> E           TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Can anyone provide some clues what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I can tell, mogrifiers returns a dictionary of all the
>   columns and any transformations that are required.

That is correct, though as you've shown it it will create a fresh dictionary each time which seems unnecessary.

> The code I am testing calls mogrify (inherited from the Base class)
>   with a specific column name in a string.
>
> This tries to extract the column from the dictionary and returns the
>   lambda function ? or if it doesn't exist in the dictionary, it returns
>   a lambada that just gives the string back ?

Yes, that is also correct (except that a lambada is a dance, but I think you meant lambda again).

> So that just leaves me with the (value) bit in the code I'm trying to
>   test. It's no clear what it does.

The call `self.myclass.mogrify(colkey)` returns a callable, the `(value)` simply calls it. It may be clearer if I rewrite like this:

```
fn = self.myclass.mogrify(colkey)
new_row[colkey] = fn(value)
```

splitting it into two lines will also make it clearer whether the problem is with the call `self.myclass.mogrify(colkey)` or `fn(value)`. If as seems likely it is the `fn(value)` call it means your mocked mogrify is returning a `str` instead of returning a callable; it could however be that you got the mock wrong and the mocked `mogrify` method is actually a string.

I would suggest you rewrite as shown and also insert a `print` between the two lines and see what is actually being returned.